# How to mass create with smarter_csv for an API - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api

Excuse me if the doubts are very basic, but I am new to this. I like it, but because of the housework, I am practically alone.

I have searched the internet for examples to create multiple products with a CSV file using the smarter_csv gem FOR API and I have not got anything.

I really don't know if it's the same as creating for an API or not.

If you can help me with anything, I would really appreciate it.

My table is the following where I want to insert the data.

```html
 create_table "products", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "sku"
    t.string "origin_country"
    t.string "hs_code"
    t.integer "weight"
    t.string "value"
    t.string "description"
    t.string "name"
    t.string "category"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.bigint "seller_id"
    t.string "width"
    t.string "length"
    t.string "height"
    t.index ["seller_id"], name: "index_products_on_seller_id"
  end
```

And to create in the controller, it is the following:

```
def create
  seller_id = @current_user.sellers.first.id
  @product = Product.new(product_params.merge(seller_id: seller_id))
  if @product.save
    api_response({}, 'SUCCESS', ['Product created'])
  else
    api_response({}, 'ERROR', [@product.errors], 422)
  end
end
```

And the route, i know maybe it's this

```
 post '/product/upload', to: 'products#upload'
```

Do you have any suggestion for me?

Thxs in advance.

Comment: What does your CSV look like?

Comment: name,description,hs_code,sku,origin_country,weight
PS3,PS3 Console,1,UK,2                   But it could have a lot of rows

Comment: Do you have a view which has the form where the CSV will be uploaded through?

Answer (score 0):

Since processing the CSV may take a while, you should add it to a processing queue and process it in the background, you'd respond to the request right away with the id of the object in the queue, the user can latter call another API endpoint with that id to check on the status of the processing (or any errors if there were any).

You can use something like [ActiveStorage](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html) to store the uploaded file and something like [delayed_job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job) or [sidekiq](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq) to process the file in the background. You'll also need to store the associated `seller_id` along with the file and its status.

Since you'll be processing multiple records from the CSV file, you should probably do it all inside a transaction so that any error causes all other saves to be rolled back, the user can then fix and reupload the file. In your background worker:

```rb
Product.transaction do
  queue_object.update!(status: 'PROCESSING', message: "Your CSV file is being processed.")

  seller_id = queue_object.seller_id
  seller = Seler.find(seller_id);

  # I'm using the standard ruby CSV lib
  CSV.foreach(queue_object.file_path, 'r', headers: true).with_index do |row, i|
    # Call it with `!` so it raises an exception if validation fails, causing the transaction to rollback
    seller.products.create!(
      name: row['name'],
      description: row['description'],
      ...
    )
  end

# Capture validation errors
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid => e
  queue_object.update!(status: 'ERROR', message: "Error in row ##{i+1}: #{e.record.errors.to_json}")
  raise # Re-raise the error so it stops the transaction
# This will be raised if the seller is not found
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound => e
  queue_object.update!(status: 'ERROR', message: "Error in row ##{i+1}: #{e.message}")
  raise
# All other exceptions
rescue => e
  queue_object.update!(status: 'ERROR', message: "Error in row ##{i+1}: #{e.message}")
  raise
else
  # If there were no errors...
  queue_object.update!(status: 'SUCCESS', message: 'File processed successfully')
ensure
  # Delete the file here if you're not going to use it anymore
end
```